# Strip tags from a WordPress Function

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Trying to print my custom post type's taxonomy but without the link. Tried this, but doesn't seem to work, any suggestions?

```
$text = the_terms($post->ID,'type','','',''); 
echo strip_tags($text);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I'm about to start punching babies.

Comment: I don't know enough about Wordpress to offer much help, but did you know that there's [a Wordpress-specific Stackexchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

`the_terms()` display the terms, but you cant store them into a variable because they are echoed. You should try [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) instead.

```
$myterms = get_terms('category', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0');
```

For future use, the `the_something()` methods print the specific content ito the template and the `get_something()` methods return the content so you can store it into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Found on the answer on the other board. Here's a link.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/strip-tags-from-a-the-terms-function/